# Calculating monthly price gains using 2 separate DateFrames in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to calculate the price gain of user’s share market transactions.

I have 2 DataFrames:

the first has purchase data. This is called ‘buys’. Sample below.

```
Acceptance_Date Symbol  Username    Volume
01-Jan-2017       FB      John       423
01-Jan-2017       FB      Lucy       58
01-Jan-2017       FB      Jeff       49,548
```

the second has stock market data. This is called ‘market’. Sample below.

```
Symbol  Date    Open    Close
FB    1-Jan-16  80.00   81.00
FB    1-Apr-16  90.00   91.00
FB    1-Jul-16  100.00  101.00
FB    1-Jan-17  110.00  110.00
```

I want to calculate the 1, 3, 6 and 12 month performance for each purchase.

Therefore the logic should be: if a user buys on 1-Jan-2016, what is the value increase of the stock on 1-Apr-2016?

The output should be an updated purchase dataframe that looks like this:

```
Acceptance_Date Symbol  Username    Volume   one_month  two_month
01-Jan-2017       FB      John       423         x%         x%
01-Jan-2017       FB      Lucy       58          x%         x%
01-Jan-2017       FB      Jeff       49,548      x%         x%
```

I feel like I’m going about it in an incredibly inefficient way. I can smash this in Excel in 2 minutes, but am struggling to get my head around it in Python/Pandas (which I’m new to).

This is the code I have tried, which feels like smashing a rock at the keys. Please help!

```
#create a df to combine purchase data and market data
purchase_df = pd.merge(market[['Symbol', 'Date', 'Close']], 
    buys[['Symbol', 'Acceptance_Date']], 
    left_on=['Symbol', 'Date'], right_on=['Symbol', 'Acceptance_Date'])

#create a new column "one_month" and add the purchase date plus one month
one_month = pd.to_datetime(buys['Acceptance_Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date + relativedelta(months =+ 1)
buys['one_month'] = one_month

#merge purchase_df with the one_month price data 
month_forward = pd.merge(market[['Symbol', 'Date', 'Close']], 
    buys[['Symbol', 'one_month']], 
    left_on=['Symbol', 'Date'], right_on=['Symbol', 'one_month'])

#calculate the gain
one_month_gain = (month_forward.close - purchase_df.close) / purchase_df.close

#repeat again for months 3, 6 and 12 then merge
```

Comment: I don't know if I can help, but *smashing a rock at the keys* has me laughing...

Comment: Also you will get more and better responses if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Does your solution work?

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for the feedback. I'm also new to StackOverflow so it's good to know some guidelines. I have updated the question. Hopefully it is a bit simpler now.

Comment: @wwii it does but it is very slow and I would have to hack it together 4 times to get all months working. There will be a simpler way, I just don't have that much experience with Python yet. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: The column names  you use in your code don't match the column names in the data -->````symbol```` != ```'Symbol'```.

Comment: ```one_month = pd.to_datetime(buys['Date'],...``` ```buys no longer has a 'Date' column.

Comment: ```NameError: name 'relativedelta' is not defined``` - what is ```relativedelta``` and what does it do?

Comment: @wwii 'relativedelta' is a function of dateutil.relativedata. It allows you to take a date and multiply it by X m, d or y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the simplest answer:

```
#shift the data up one cell
new_market['one_m_close'] = new_market['close'].shift(-22)
new_market['one_m_date'] = new_market['date'].shift(-22)

#calculate the gain
new_market['one_m_change'] = (new_market.one_m_close - new_market.close) / new_market.close

#then merge DataFrames with pd.merge
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

First pivot your market table so you have symbols as indices and dates as columns:

```
# assuming you are using close-to-close returns
market_pivot = market.pivot_table(index='Symbol', columns='Date', values='Close')
```

Second, define a function to get returns:

```
def get_return(ser, li_duration):
    """
    ser : pandas series, represents a row from purchase_df
    li_duration : list of int for holding periods
    """
    # do some list comprehension here to convert li_duration to end dates
    ldt_dates = [...]
    date = ser['Acceptance_Date']
    symbol = ser['Symbol']
    begin_price = market_pivot.loc[symbol, date]
    end_price = market_pivot.loc[symbol, ldt_dates]
    # calculate returns and replace the indices
    return_ser = end_price / begin_price - 1
    return_ser.index = [<desired column labels here>]
    # append the returns to purchase information
    return ser.append(return_ser)
```

now apply this function to purchase_df row by row:

```
df_result = purchase_df.apply(get_return, li_duration=[1, 3, 6, 12])
```

> Disclaimer: didn't actually run the code, just to show thought process

Comment: thanks for that, but it didn't seem to work. The logic complicated it even more. I found the simplest answer below. Thanks again for your input though.

Comment: Sorry I meant to use the 'buy' dataframe instead of purchase_df..but glad you found a solution